# how to use order_by RAND with my code below in codeigniter

Tags: php, random

i have this code :

```
$select = ['account_access_token','account_config_id'];
```

```
$where = ['where'=>['enable_marketing' => '1', 'account_config_id.id!=' => $account_table_id]];
```

```
$join
=['account_user_info'=>'account_config_id.account_user_info_id=account_user_info.id,left'];
```

```
$pages_info = $this->basic->get_data('account_config_id',$where,$select,$join);
```

so as you see i want to load an account into my target page

my question is :
how to load the $pages_info results randomly ?

i tried to add : RAND(), $order_by='RAND()'
but its dosen't work
every time the account id=$id is loaded with no change
thanks a lot in Advanced

no luck with search

Comment: Which framework or CMS you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter's query builder's orderBy accepts **RANDOM** as order direction and will then ignore the first parameter (usually the field name), unless the first parameter is numeric, in which case it will be used to seed **RAND()**.

```
$builder->orderBy('account_config_id', 'DESC');
// Produces: ORDER BY `account_config_id` DESC

$builder->orderBy('account_config_id', 'ASC');
// Produces: ORDER BY `account_config_id` ASC

$builder->orderBy('account_config_id', 'RANDOM');
// Produces: ORDER BY RAND()

$builder->orderBy(12, 'RANDOM');
// Produces: ORDER BY RAND(12)
```